# Como é possivel clonarem cartões no meu site?

Tags: php, html, asp.net-mvc, asp

o que esta ocorrendo é o seguinte. Atualmente estou tentando resolver um grande problema, duas das lojas virtuais da empresa que atendo estão com problema de clonagem de cartões. Não tenho muita experiência nisso, mas vou explicar como esta funcionando hoje o sistema de cartão.

1) Cliente informa os dados de cartão no carrinho de compras.
2) Um ajax envia essas informações para um arquivo .asp e e processa o pagamento e devolve o retorno.

As lojas:

- Usam SSL.
- Não salvam nada no banco de dados referente ao cartão.
- O Servidor disse que não tem virus.

Quais ações posso tomar para tentar resolver isso? Falando em programação.

Comment: Algum funcionário tem acesso a essas informações? Vc checou o log de acesso no servidor para ver se tem alguém entrando lá e capturando alguma coisa?

Comment: ninguém tem acesso, as informações não ficam gravadas em lugar nenhum.

Comment: E não teria como eles pegarem a informação "em transito" durante a validação... Tipo um bot que fica esperando o evento executar e pega o que estiver no script algo do tipo?

Comment: Essa também é minha duvida? Como posso evitar isso? qual tratamento usar? Como posso descobrir se é isso?

Comment: quando o cara se registra no seu site o cartão de crédito dele não fica gravado mesmo ? todas as compras que ele fizer ele terá q redigitar o número do cartão ?

Comment: Como o tal bot vai quebrar a segurança do SSL??

Comment: nada fica gravado. Todo vez tem que redigitar tudo;

Comment: o ajax que envia os dados para o .asp tbm faz o envio dos dados por ssl ?

Comment: É, seu `$.ajax()` tem algo como `url: 'https://blablabla.com/blablabla'`?

Comment: sim, tem a url ou pelo menos é possível identifica-la inspecionando. Como resolvo?

Comment: se a url que o seu ajax envia para o .asp usa ssl, as coisas não me cheiram bem :-(

Comment: Não cheguei a olhar isso, pode ser que a url de destino, a que recebe o post e processa os dados do pagamento não usem ssl.

Comment: Mas tem `https` na `url:`?

Comment: o ajax esta mandando o post para o arquivo, exemplo: pagamento_cartao.asp. Não tem a url completa na chamada do ajax.

Comment: havia um injection deste javascript no banco de dados do sistema, https://cdn.rawgit.com/0shrk/web/master/p.js ele é estranho às funcionalidades da loja, deve ter sido isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando token anti-fraude (AntiForgeryToken)?

Pode ser que, no pagamento do carrinho de compras, em vez de clicar uma vez, o cliente esteja fazendo duplo clique no botão Pagar.

Se isto estiver acontecendo e você não usar o token, o pagamento será processado mais de uma vez.

Se você validar tokens desse tipo, uma vez que o usuário tenha feito o POST do <FORM>ulário de pagamento e usado um token, o token deixará de ser válido e novas tentativas de uso desse mesmo token, que aconteceria caso ele tenha apertado o botão inúmeras vezes, falharão.

Para usar o AntiForgeryToken, basta decorar o método do controller com:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pagar(PagamentoModel model)
{
    ....
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Marcelão, sem ofensas ok, mas só para te dar o toque mesmo. Vc não acha que o campo de comentário seria mais adequado para o seu questionamento? Não é correto usar o campo de resposta para fazer perguntas e tirar dúvidas sobre a pergunta....

Comment: Blz vlw flw abs

Comment: Marcelo, não, mas eu acho que isso não causaria o problema de clonagem do cartão. O problema é que quem compra nas lojas tem o cartão clonado. Porém, nada do cartão é salvo no banco de dados.

Comment: Como ficou sabendo que o(s) cartão(ões) eram clonados? Se existe um rastreio dessa clonagem, talvez ficaria mais fácil entender. Vocês receberam duas ou mais vezes pelo pagamento em um mesmo cartão? Se foi isso, então não custa verificar *como* o usuário operou seu carrinho de compras.

Comment: Não, o problema é que quem compra nos meus sites, reclama que tentaram comprar com seu cartao em outros sites (outras lojas) posteriormente, e isso começou a ficar muito frequente. Depois das compras nas minhas lojas, aparece tentativas de compras em outros locais que o dono do cartao nao reconhece.

Comment: Já verificou se você não está usando JS de outros hosts que não o seu? Pode ser que algum JS seu ou algum CDN que tenha JS seu esteja vulnerável?

Comment: Não esta usando não.

Comment: Olá a todos, justamente isso @MarceloUchimura encontrei no banco muito escondido um injection deste javascript que é estranho ao sistema. https://cdn.rawgit.com/0shrk/web/master/p.js acredito ser isso.

Comment: Ok, @AndersonNunes, valeu pela resposta. Por favor, providencie uma análise geral do site para vulnerabilidades com SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

Vamos lá, baseado nas informações dos seus comentários, estamos de fora sem acesso aos logs, sem acesso ao servidor, sem acesso aos seus códigos, só podemos presumir onde o problema está acontecendo.

```
 - Usam SSL.
```

Se todas as comunicações utilizam `SSL` o problema morre aqui...Quando eu digo `todas as comunicações` quero dizer que o seu site deve fazer toda a comunicação entre browser(cliente) e o seu server via `https:`, outro ponto é se o seu `ajax` envia os dados para o `.asp` utilizando comunicação `SSL`, se a resposta for OK, seria muito complicado alguém conseguir interceptar(sniffar, spoofar) a comunicação entre browser(cliente) e o server(nginx, apache, IIS, etc), também seria muito complicado forjar o `SSL` para tentar pegar os dados de maneira nua...

Se o envio dos dados entre o seu `ajax` e o `.asp` não for criptografado, qualquer `sniffer` ou `arp spoof` rodando na rede onde está o seu server poderá ler essas informação, o mesmo acontece na rede onde está recebendo os dados, no seu caso a rede onde está o `.asp`, em ambos os casos você é refém, não tem controle sobre nenhuma das redes, senta e chora, ou garanta que tudo está criptografado

`- Não salvam nada no banco de dados referente ao cartão`.

Se você garante que nada é salvo em lugar nenhum, esqueça problemas de invasão de banco e sql injections

```
 - O Servidor disse que não tem virus.
```

Isso é muito vago, o problema pode estar ocorrendo aqui sim, pode ser servidor ou vulnerabilidade no seu código, de nada adianta tudo estar criptografado via ssl, se o seu servidor estiver comprometido, alguma porta ftp aberta, porta ssh aberta, algo que pode ser explorado por exploits e permitir acesso total ao servidor, isso garantiria que o atacante mude códigos de maneira oculta e envie formulários para o servidor/pc/banco de dado dele... o mesmo pode acontecer com os seus códigos php/asp, se tiver algum furo neles, o atacante pode inserir códigos ocultos no seu servidor sem você tomar conhecimento algum.

Imagine que o `Hacker` consiga uma maneira de acessar o seu servidor, ele pode conseguir isso explorando o http/ssh/ftp/exploits/brechas no código(php, asp), etc, imagine que estou no formulário e que estou digitando o número do meu cartão de crédito, ok os dados estão criptografados via ssl assim que eu apertar o submit ninguém em teoria conseguiria ler a transação, mas os dados no formulário contido no lado do servidor não estão criptografados, alguém poderia inserir em algum local do código algo que guardasse ou enviasse esses dados...

```
  - Quais ações posso tomar para tentar resolver isso? Falando em   
    programação
```

Sem saber com certeza onde está o problema não tem como chutar :-(

Comment: Dá uma lida nesse case https://blog.sucuri.net/portugues/2017/09/seguranca-de-ecommerce-jquery-falso-rouba-cartoes-de-credito.html

Comment: @MarcosXavier sim exatamente, só é possível inserir algo no código se o servidor estiver comprometido de alguma maneira, foi sobre isso que escrevi no penúltimo e ultimo parágrafo :-(

Comment: Exatamente, no post do link tem algumas sugestões. Acredito que seja um dos primeiros passos pra você auditar e resolver a falha. Verifique sobre a possibilidade de javascript injection, é uma suposição já que não conheço como o sistema está desenhado